# NGINX IP Transparency on SSL Stream

Tags: nginx, ssl, load-balancing

I am setting up a server cluster with NGINX as the load balancer. All requests are over HTTPS and as such the load balancer uses passes the request straight to the cluster with streams (SSL Pass-through).

I need the end servers to see the client IP instead of the load balancer IP.

My nginx.conf

```
## Misc other config stuff

stream {
  map $ssl_preread_server_name $backend_cluster_map {
    site.a cluster_1;
    site.b cluster_2;
    default cluster_1;
  }

  upstream cluster_1 {
    server 10.0.0.202:443;
    server 10.0.0.203:443;
  }

  upstream cluster_2 {
    server 10.0.0.204:443;
    server 10.0.0.205:443;
  }

  server {
    listen 443;
    proxy_pass $backend_cluster_map;
    ssl_preread on;
  }
}
```

I tried changing the server block to include `proxy_set_header` to forward the IP but that didn't pass the nginx test, stating `proxy_set_header directive is not allowed here`.

```
server {
  listen 443;
  proxy_protocol on;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Fowarded-Proto https;
  proxy_set_header X-Fowarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Fowarded-Host $remote_addr;
  proxy_pass $backend_cluster_map;
  ssl_preread on;
}
```

I imagine its has something to do with not being able to change the SSL request. Any alternatives? I'm trying not to terminate the SSL at the load balancer.

Comment: You cannot set any headers since you cannot change the payloads. Apart from that X-Forwarded-For would not be IP transparency but only provides information about the original client IP at the HTTP level, i.e. application layer instead of network layer like you want. For configuring IP transparency see [this official documentation](https://www.nginx.com/blog/ip-transparency-direct-server-return-nginx-plus-transparent-proxy/#ip-transparency) instead.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich great answer!

Answer (score 5):

Built off what Steffen Ullrich said I followed https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/proxy-protocol/.

On the end servers I added

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl proxy_protocol;
  ...
  set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.201;
  real_ip_header proxy_protocol;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $proxy_protocol_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Fowarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
  ...
}
```

and on the load balancer

```
server {
  listen 443;
  proxy_protocol on; # Make sure this is enabled
  proxy_pass $backend_cluster_map;
  ...
}
```

And the application now sees the client IP address not the load balancer's with SSL passthrough.

Comment: Great! Just what I was looking for!

Comment: +1 beer for Jed. Thank you. I was missing the fact that `set_real_ip_from` is to be set to the upstream proxy's IP (in this case 127.0.0.1). IOW, `set_real_ip_from` tells the stream-server to derive the client IP from what the upstream (proxy-)server 127.0.0.1 is propagating via the PROXY protocol. I always stopped reading at "Defines trusted addresses [...]" wondering what trust has got to do with proxying. See https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html#set_real_ip_from . Also, read this https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/, great stuff.